# C# Convert int to short and then to bytes and back to int

Tags: c#

I'm trying to convert **int** to **short** and then to **byte[]** but I'm getting wrong values, i pass in 1 and get 256 what am i doing wrong? 
this is the code:

```
//passing 1
int i = 1;
byte[] shortBytes = ShortAsByte((short)i);

//ii is 256
short ii = Connection.BytesToShort (shortBytes [0], shortBytes [1]);

public static byte[] ShortAsByte(short shortValue){
    byte[] intBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(shortValue);
    if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian) Array.Reverse(intBytes);
    return intBytes;
}

public static short BytesToShort(byte byte1, byte byte2)
{
    return (short)((byte2 << 8) + byte1);
}
```

Comment: you care about endianness in shortasbyte, but assume that byte2 is the most significant byte when calling bytestoshort. swap the order of arguments to `BytesToShort`, or make it `(byte1 << 8) + byte2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `ShortAsByte` has the most significant bit at index 0 and the least significant at index 1, so the `BytesToShort` method is shifting a 1 instead of a 0. This means `BytesToShort` returns 256 (1 << 8 + 0 = 256) instead of 1 (0 << 8 + 1 = 1) .

Swap the byte variables in the return statement to get the correct result.

```
public static short BytesToShort(byte byte1, byte byte2)
{
    return (short)((byte1 << 8) + byte2);
}
```

Also, props to you for taking endian-ness into consideration!